# Dynamic limit in Firestore?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want to be able to change how many items I'm showing by changing the `.limit` filter every time the user clicks View More. The problem is that the `.limit` doesn't seem to update when I change the variable. Is this a known issue?

**Typescript**

```
clicks = 1;

this.activitiesCollection = this.afs.collection(activitiesPath, ref => {
    return ref.orderBy('date', 'desc').limit(3 * this.clicks)      //NOT CHANGING
});

this.activities = this.activitiesCollection.valueChanges();

clicker() {
    this.clicks++;
    console.log(this.clicks)       //UPDATING VARIABLE COUNT PROPERLY
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let activity of activities | async">
    {{activity.name}}
</div>

<button (click)="clicker()">View more</button>
```

Comment: Is the Typescript file your component's class? Can you share your whole component? And why are you using `var` to define a member of the component?

Comment: clicks should be defined as `public clicks: number = 1;` instead. Try `console.log(this.clicks);` right above the line where you're using `.limit(3 * this.clicks)` to see if the variable is changing.

Comment: I added `var` by accident in this SO example. Yes, the code under Typescript is in my component class. I'm doing `console.log(this.clicks)` (see edit) in the `clicker()` function and it is updating the variable count just fine, just not updating the `.limit` for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Question posted on Github with response [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1468).